# Pip error in virtualenv

Tags: pip

I created a virtualenv by typing 
      virtualenv --no-site-packages newgame

I then initiated the virtualenv by cd'ing into my newgame folder and typing 
      source bin/active.

This seems to have worked because I now see (newgame)Benjamins-MacBook:newgame test in terminal.

Now THIS is the part where I'm stuck. I type pip install lpthw.web and I get the following

```
-bash: /Users/test/Python Projects/newgame/bin/pip: "/Users/test/Python: bad interpreter:        No such file or directory
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It's a [bug in virtualenv](https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/issues/53), it cannot handle paths with spaces in them (your `Python Projects`).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick script to remove spaces in your file names/directories:

```
function serenity-now() {
    for i in *;
    do
        if [ -f "$i" ];
        then
            mv "$i" "`echo $i | sed -e 's, ,-,g'`";
        # fi;
        # if [ ( -d "$i" ) && ( $i != $(echo $i | sed -e 's, ,-,g') ) ];
        elif [ -d "$i" ];
        then
            if [ $i != $(echo $i | sed -e 's, ,-,g') ];
            then
                mv "$i" "$(echo $i | sed -e 's, ,-,g')";
            fi;
        fi;
    done;
    find . -type f -name "*~" -exec rm {} \;
    # \rm *.xls* *.doc* *.ppt*;
}
```

The last line is optional, but does help clean things up.